# What's the easiest way to get inputs with rounded corners?

Tags: jsx, semantic-ui-react

Currently I'm working on a React page with Semantic UI, and I'm struggling to find the easiest way to get Input components with rounded corners. Just applying border-radius as normal doesn't seem to work; does anyone have any better ideas?

(To clarify - I'm looking for basically the same look at the Search component in Semantic-React.)

Comment: How are you applying `border-radius`?

Comment: For example - 
`<Input
    style={{borderRadius: '50px'}}
/>`

Comment: and what do you see in the developer tools for this css style? is it being overriden? by something specific?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The styles and rendering for Forms and Input elements in SUI and SUIR gets a little tricky. Especially once you abstract the rendered markup into React components.

What is actually happening in Semantic UI React? Let's take a look:

```
// This...

<Input placeholder='Search...' />

// Renders this in the DOM

<div class="ui input">
  <input placeholder="Search..." type="text">
</div>
```

Makes sense so far. But examining this closer, we get a clue as to where our problem lies. Where do we think the inline styles are going to be applied when we use the `styles` prop? On the outer `<div>` or on the `<input>`?

```
// This...

<Input 
  placeholder='Search...'
  styles={{borderRadius: '100px'}}
/>

// Renders this in the DOM - Not what we want :(

<div class="ui input" style="border-radius: 100px;">
  <input placeholder="Search..." type="text">
</div>
```

In theory the above might be okay if the styles for Semantic UI inputs were exclusively on the parent `div.ui.input`. Not all of them actually are. Some styles explicitly target the child `<input>` with `.ui.input > input {...}` which is where our problem lies if we want to pass styles in exclusively in React with the `styles` prop.

So, how do we get styles onto that inner `<input>` without writing separate, more specific CSS that overrides the compiled Semantic UI styles? Luckily Semantic UI React actually lets you pass an `<input>` as React `children`. Take a look at this:

```
// This...
<Input placeholder='Search...'>
  <input style={{borderRadius: '100px'}} />
</Input>

// Gives us this, which is what we want!
<div class="ui input">
  <input placeholder="Search..." type="text" style="border-radius: 100px;"> . 
</div>
```

Hopefully you find this answer to your earlier question in time to help you out. I threw in a quick screenshot below to show what this looks like.

[image]

Comment: This is fantastic, thank you very much - it's a total solution to my problem!

Comment: the effect of icon is missing

Comment: my solution is to add the icon after input like this <i aria-hidden='true' class='lock icon' /> and this works